# CSS: Left align contents of TD where INPUT exists

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying in CSS to left align the contents of a TD cell when there is an Input in it. The Input should be left aligned. Is this possible?

```
 <td> <input ....Left Align Me... /></td>
```

Comment: I wish it were... I'd love to be able to style a parent based on its children but for now... it isn't possible. :-(

Comment: Why are you using an `input` inside a table cell?

Comment: With JavaScript you could do the manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are making a basic form, probably with labels in an adjacent cell. If so, I'd use the <th> (table column header) tag for the labels like so:

CSS:

```
#tableId td {text-align: left; }
#tableId th {text-align: right; font-weight: normal}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="tableId">
<tr>
<th>Label</th>
<td><input id="test"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If your table is more complex the next easiest way would be to simply add a class name to the cells you want to left-align to target them in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
td input {
    float: left;
}
```

It's not *exactly* what you want, but it's as close as you're gonna get with pure CSS.